# How to restore application with the same size?

Tags: c#, user32

When I have an application opened and I try to open again it, i want to restore the application launched with the actual size.

The code used is this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);

private const int SW_SHOW = 5;

public static void SetForegroundMyWindow(IntPtr windowHandle)
{
    SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
    ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);
}
```

With this code, when the window is maximized, the application is shown with the size without maximize.
Only with `SetForegroundWindow`, the application is not shown when it is minimized.

What is the way to get my window with the actual size?

Comment: You tagged this as C#. So my question is must you use p/invokes here or can you use the Settings Property of the application and bind the window size to the settings?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, i use p/invokes

Comment: I see that you do, but **must** you?

Comment: Have you tried the `SetWindowPos` method? [pinvoke.net has samples](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowPos)

Comment: I have the same problem with minimized windows, I can't see them.